# Django Query - Instances with single count

Tags: django

I have the following classes:

```
class Company(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Group(Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   country = CountryField(default='US')
```

There are instances where a company can have multiple groups in a single country. I want to fetch all the company groups that are just the only ones in their respective countries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a not exists subquery for `Company` using [`Exists()` subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) while excluding the `pk` of the `Group` and filtering for matching `company` and `country`:

```py
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

# will refer outer query as OQ in below comments

# Subquery to find any matching row of a particular row excluding the specified row
subquery = Group.objects.filter(
    company=OuterRef('company'),  # companies matching the current row of OQ
    country=OuterRef('country')  # countries matching the current row of OQ
).exclude(pk=OuterRef('pk'))  # exclude current row of OQ

# find groups for which no entry exists in subquery
groups = Group.objects.filter(~Exists(subquery))
```

**Note**: If you use a version of Django < 3.0 you cannot directly filter on an `Exists` subquery, you will need to annotate it first:

```py
# annotate the subquery first and filter on that
groups = Group.objects.annotate(similar_groups=Exists(subquery)).filter(similar_groups=False)
```

Comment: This would not work. Need to find companies' single groups per country and not just single groups per company.

Comment: `CountryField` is a foreign key right? You can just do the same thing above but for Country -> Group

Comment: CountryField isn't a Django model so that wont work as well

Comment: @ted check my edit, I believe that should do it.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I get `TypeError: 'Exists' object is not iterable`

Comment: @ted do you use a version of Django < 3.0? You cannot use `filter` on `Exists` subquery directly in those versions, see the edit.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that works. Thanks. Care to explain what you did? Will really appreciate

Comment: @ted I think my explanation was clear in the answer but tried to explain a bit more in the comments in the code.